# NSIS zipDLL.nsh not working with NSIS portable version

Tags: nsis

I'm trying to compile a script, perfectly working with NSIS installing version, by NSIS partable version but it doesn't work.

Other `.nsh` files, also natively available in `Include` folder of NSIS portable version, called by the script are working well. The web downloaded `zipdll.nsh` file, added in a second time into the `Include` folder of NSIS portable version, is at moment the only file called by the script that doesn't work!

The compiler gets back the following message:

```
!include: "C:\PortableApps\NSISPortable\App\NSIS\Include\zipdll.nsh" (UTF8)
!define: "ZIPDLL_USED"=""
Bad text encoding
!include: error in script: "C:\PortableApps\NSISPortable\App\NSIS\Include\zipdll.nsh" on line 77
```

Does anybody of you know how to put me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance to everyone who will help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That file contains multiple languages but is not valid UTF-8 so you have to force the codepage:

```
!include /CHARSET=CP1252 zipdll.nsh
```